# Why this code works well in Linux but failed in Windows?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, crash, linked-list

I write some code of linked list:
The definition of linked list:

```
struct Node {
    // data is used to store an integer value in this node
    int data;
    // a pointer points to the next node
    Node* link;
    // inializes the node with a 0 value in data and a null pointer in link
    Node() : data(0), link(NULL) {};
    // destructor release space allocated to the linked list
    ~Node() {delete link;}
};
```

display linked list:

```
void display_and_count(Node* aLink) {
    cout << "Entries: ";
    int nodeNumber = 0;                         // elements number of linked list
    for(Node* iterator = aLink; iterator->link != NULL; iterator=iterator->link) {
        cout << iterator->data << ", ";
        nodeNumber++;
    }
    cout << "contans " << nodeNumber << " nodes." << endl;
}// end display_and_count
```

Now I write a function split one linked list to two ones LESS and MORE based on a threshold and remove nodes in original linked list:

```
void split_them_up(Node* aLink, Node* less, Node* more, int threshold) {
    Node* lessHead = less;                              // head of less
    Node* moreHead = more;                              // head of more
    bool isThresholdInALink = false;                    // store if threshold is an element of aLink
    for(Node* iterator = aLink; iterator->link != NULL; iterator = iterator->link) {
        if(iterator->data < threshold) {
            less->data = iterator->data;
            less->link = new Node;
            less = less->link;
        }
        else if(iterator->data > threshold) {
            more->data = iterator->data;
            more->link = new Node;
            more = more->link;
        }
        else {
            isThresholdInALink = true;
        }
    } // end for(Node* iterator = aLink; iterator->link != NULL; iterator = iterator->link)

    less = lessHead;
    more = moreHead;

    delete aLink;
    // If threshold is an element of aLink, then the new linked list contains the only threshold.
    // If threshold isn't in aLink, then the new linked list contains nothing
    aLink = new Node;
    if(isThresholdInALink) {
        aLink->data = threshold;
        aLink->link = new Node;
    } // end if(isThresholdInALink)*/
} // end split_them_up
```

Then this is main function:

```
int main() {
    Node* ENTRIES = new Node;           // define a linked list

    get_input(ENTRIES);
    display_and_count(ENTRIES);

    Node* less = new Node;              // define less list
    Node* more = new Node;              // define more list
    cout << "Enter a threshold: ";
    int thd;                            // threshold
    cin >> thd;
    split_them_up(ENTRIES, less, more, thd);

    cout << "Less list: " << endl;
    display_and_count(less);
    cout << "More list: " << endl;
    display_and_count(more);
    cout << "ENTRIES: " << endl;
    display_and_count(ENTRIES);
}
```

get_input function get some integer from user and -1 to end:

```
void get_input(Node* aLink) {
    Node* head = aLink;                 // head of linked list
    int capacity=1;                     // the capacity of intArray
    int* intArray = new int[capacity];  // an array stores user input
    int size=0;                         // actual number of elements stored in the intArray

    cout << "Input some integers, -1 to end: ";
    while(true) {
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        if(input == -1) break;
        if(!isContained(intArray, size, input)) {
            intArray[size]=input;
            size++;
            // if size meets capacity, double capacity
            if(size >= capacity) {
                int* temp = new int[capacity];
                int oldCapacity = capacity;
                for(int i=0; i < oldCapacity; i++) temp[i]=intArray[i];
                delete[] intArray;
                capacity = 2*capacity;
                intArray = new int[capacity];
                for(int i=0; i < oldCapacity; i++) intArray[i]=temp[i];
                delete[] temp;
            } // end if(size >= capacity)
        } // end if(!contained(intArray, size, input))
    } // end while(true)

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        aLink->data = intArray[i];
        aLink->link = new Node;
        aLink = aLink->link;
    }
    delete[] intArray;
    aLink = head;
} // end get_input
```

isContained:

```
bool isContained(int* array, int aSize, int n) {
    for(int i=0; i<aSize; i++) {
        if(array[i] == n) return true;
    }
    return false;
} // end isContained
```

When executing in Linux system everything is OK. But in windows it will show a random value in ENTRIES after split_them_up and program will crash giving a "Access violation reading location".

Comment: *Where does it crash?* If you can't answer this question you probably haven't used a debugger yourself yet and shouldn't ask this question on SO (yet).

Comment: In main function the last line: display_and_count(ENTRIES);

Comment: You have too much code in this post, nobody is going to read all of it. You should try to slim it down, maybe reproduce your issue in a smaller test program.

Comment: You do realize your `less` and `more` pointers passed to `split_them_up` are passed by-value and therefore assigning to them with code like `less = lessHead;` means absolutely nothing to the outside caller, right? Also, `main()` leaks both nodes allocated and assigned to `less` and `more`. Finally, I don't advise using `less` as a variable name of any kind in code that includes the standard headers, as `std::less<>` is a library defined comparator and bound to cause either confusion or outright bugs.

Comment: Please compile with `g++ -Wall -g`, improve the code till no warnings are given, then debug the code with the `gdb` debugger and the `valgrind` memory leak detector; you probably have a memory issue... the fact that the program apparently complete correctly on Linux don't mean there is no leak (or premature `free` or `delete`) or some other memory issue.

Comment: You are coding in C++, so why not use `std::list` or some other container?

Comment: @WhozCraig: could you clarify the meaning of your comment "`main()` leaks both nodes"?  Surely C++ does not oblige you to delete objects before exiting the program?

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, it certainly does not *require* it, but on that regard why dynamically allocate them in the first place? It is simply bad practice. Ex. Were those of a class type that required destruction (such as finalizing data-writes, flushing, and closing  file handles) said-closure is lost without deleting what you allocate. Another ex: copy/paste this into its own function. Ouch. You are correct in that obviously on process termination your allocated resources are returned to the OS (as if they were ever yours to begin with). But it is a bad habit not to clean up ones leavings.

Comment: @WhozCraig: it's equally bad practice to free memory unnecessarily during process exit.  Firefox does this, and it's a major pain; on my work machine, it often takes several minutes to shut down, and I can't start it up again until it's done.  See also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/01/05/10253268.aspx for an expert opinion.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm sorry *Firefox'* design choices running on your platform-choice eats minutes out of your life during shutdown,  and equally sorry that it is inconvenient for you when it does so. But I stan firm: it is a *bad-habit*, that opinion shared by a decent ratio of apparently equally naive non-experts in your linked discussion. Try as he might to reign in the original discussion topic (DLL_PROCESS_DETACH handling), Mr. Chen was fighting a storm surge. After 24 years in this business (six more and I get a free set of steak knives and *maybe* qualify as "expert") I'm not surprised.

Comment: @WhozCraig: re-reading that discussion, I'm inclined to think of this as a weakness in C++, albeit probably not a serous one; it encourages use of the constructor/destructor pattern to avoid actual thought about what the object is doing and whether or not destruction is necessary in any given case.  It may also encourage people to cut-and-paste without thought, on the assumption that the code was written for the general rather than the specific case.  However, I'm quite prepared to accept that *in C++* you shouldn't leak objects from main.  It's not directly relevant to the OPs problem anyway.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I definitely agree to that. An affordance for this type of thing as an attribute to the language and destruction would be complicated, but definitely welcome for situations where, as you put it, it really shouldn't be necessary to clean up a bunch of who-cares-data. As-is, you could code to get similar behavior, but a language-based solution would likely be far more elegant, to be sure. I completely understand the points you made, by the way. Thankfully (or luckily) I've nerve found myself that deep in the junk that cleanup was an issue. I hope never to be =P

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve the problem, but i'm pretty sure you do not want a destructor like that for the node.

1. There's no new, so there's no need for a delete.
2. How are you going to implement deletion of a certain node of a list if it triggers deletion of the next node, and the next, and the next...?

Comment: I have a destructor in linked list, so I think when implementing deletion it will call the destructor and then next node and the next

Comment: this is not how lists usually work. one node should not be able to act on other nodes, let alone delete them.

it's the list of nodes that manages these things.
EDIT: since you don't have a list object, it would be your main.cpp who has the responsibility to delete the nodes it created.

Comment: Yes I think the problem may be this. But why it works well in Linux?

Comment: Honestly, i have no idea. I haven't parsed all of your code, though, there might be more subtle mistakes I missed

Answer (score 0):

Of course you'll crash when manipulating `ENTRIES`; the `split_them_up` function deleted the `Node` object that it points to.

From the looks of it, you intended to declare `aLink` as pointer-to-pointer so that you can actually change the value of `ENTRIES` to point to the newly declared `Node` (which at the moment you are leaking).

Alternatively, instead of deleting `aLink` you could delete the child node and reuse `aLink`, i.e., replace this:

```
delete aLink;
aLink = new Node;
if(isThresholdInALink) {
    aLink->data = threshold;
    aLink->link = new Node;
}
```

with this:

```
delete aLink->link;
if(isThresholdInALink) {
    aLink->data = threshold;
    aLink->link = new Node;
} else {
    aLink->data = 0;
    aLink->link = NULL;
}
```

Why does the bad code work on Linux?  At a guess, the newly declared `Node` is coincidentally created in the same location as the original deleted node, so `ENTRIES` accidentally points to the right place.

I'll also comment that you don't need `lessHead` or `moreHead`; they're not doing anything useful.  Remove them completely.  Just like `aHead`, since `less` and `more` are not declared as pointers-to-pointers, the values in the calling function won't be affected by anything that happens inside `split_them_up`.

*Additional:* the destructor,

```
~Node() {delete link;}
```

is liable to overflow the stack if the link is large.  Recursion is a fine thing, but not when carried to extremes. :-)